# How to validate a list of different dictionaries with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, json, django, validation, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework 2.4.

The data that I want to serialize, kind of looks like this.
I am kind of making a Google Form like Application where I have to validate a dynamic form using a specified template which contains some JSON text that is used to validate the feedback form.

```
{
 "template" : <template-id>,
 "name" : <some-name>,
 "answers" : [{"value":"kkkk"},{"value":"123"},{"value":"[\"hello\", \"world\"]"}]
}
```

"*template*" is something that gets us the template's json from the database. 
I need a way to validate the answers field's format based on an array of rules that template has in form of json for each index of the answer.

Template is a model, that has an *id* and *fields_json* as fields. 
*fields_json* looks like this:

```
[{"type":"text", "pattern":"alphanumeric"},{"type":"number", "range":[10,20]}, {"type":"list", "max_length":2}]
```

Now when my API receives the data, I can get the template from the database, using template-id.
but then now the answers array should be validated depending on what rule the filds_json has at that index.

Comment: Do you have any code so far (models, serializers, etc)? It's possible do this, but writing an answer that handles the general case is going to be difficult without some code to start from.

Comment: I have but it will need a little clean up before I post it here. I will post a simpler version here, the one I am actually working in is quite complex.